# Removing characters in a file and also making it neat

Tags: python, file, split

I want to basically remove all the characters in delete list from the file (Line 11 to 15). What would be the neatest way to delete the words without making the code not neat. I am not sure whether to open the file again here which I know would not be the right way but I can't think of a different solution. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from os import write
import re

def readText():
    with open(r'C:\Users\maxth\Desktop\TextCounter\Text.txt') as f:
        print(f.read())

def longestWord():
     with open(r'C:\Users\maxth\Desktop\TextCounter\Text.txt', 'r+') as f:
        users_text = f.read()
        #I want to basically remove all the char in delete list from the file. What would be the neatest way to delete the words without making the code not neat. I am not sure wether to open the file again here and re write it or what!
        deleteList = ['!','£','$','%','^','&','*','()','_','+']
        for line in f:
            for word in deleteList:
                line = line.replace(word, '')
        
        longest = max(users_text.split(), key=len) 
        count_longest = str(len(longest))
        print('The longest word in the file is: ' + long)
        print('Thats a total of '+count_longest+' letters!')

def writeWord():
    with open(r'C:\Users\maxth\Desktop\TextCounter\Text.txt', 'w') as f:
        users_text = input('Enter your desired text to continue. \n: ')
        f.write(users_text)
        f.close()
        with open(r'C:\Users\maxth\Desktop\TextCounter\Text.txt', 'r') as file:
            print(file.read())

longestWord()
```

Comment: if you do `f.read()` then it will not work `for line in f` because it is at the end of file. Simply remove `users_text = f.read()` and work with `for line in f:` and  `append()` new `line` to list. OR work only with `users_text = f.read()` and run `for`-loop with `user_text = user_text.replace(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Had to re work it and implement it in a different def. Need to add relative paths and will be alot cleaner aswell.

```
from os import write
import re

def longestWord():
     with open(r'C:\Users\maxth\Desktop\TextCounter\Text.txt', 'r+') as f:
        users_text = f.read()    
        longest = max(users_text.split(), key=len) 
        count_longest = str(len(longest))
        print('The longest word in the file is: ' + longest)
        print('Thats a total of '+count_longest+' letters!')

def writeWord():
    with open(r'C:\Users\maxth\Desktop\TextCounter\Text.txt', 'w') as f:
        users_text = input('Enter your desired text to continue. \n: ')
        cleanText = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9 \n\.]', ' ', users_text)
        f.write(cleanText)
        with open(r'C:\Users\maxth\Desktop\TextCounter\Text.txt', 'r') as clean:
            print('\nRemoved any illegal characters. Here is your text:\n\n' + cleanText + '\n')
        f.close()

while True:
    print("""
Welcome to Skies word text counter!
====================================================
""")
    writeWord()
    longestWord()
    userDecide = input("""
====================================================
Would you like to enter new text and repeat?
Type 'yes' to continue else program will terminate.
====================================================
: """)
    if not userDecide.lower == 'yes':
        print('Application closing...')
        exit()
```